# `ldap_compare` returns false for all attributes/value pairs

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to authenticate user via LDAP (active directory). `ldap_compare` show `Warning: ldap_compare(): Compare: Operations error in /mehr/public/lab/lab.php on line 26` warning and returns `-1`. The warning is vague for me. What is wrong with it?

```
<?php 
$ldap = ldap_connect("179.33.2.200");
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); // Recommended for AD
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$bind = ldap_bind($ldap, 'admin', '123456');

$bdn = 'DC=active,DC=local';
$r = ldap_compare($ldap, $bdn, 'userpassword', '123456'); 
$r = ldap_compare($ldap, $bdn, 'ou', 'bar');  // or evern
```

## Upate:

Using @Arnold hint I called ldap_compare as follow:

```
ldap_compare($ldap, $dn, 'ou', mb_convert_encoding('bar','utf16'))
```

Now, I do not get "Operations error" (using `utf-16le` cause same error.), but now it returns `false` for all attribute/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare passwords this way in Active Directory.

First of all, the passwords are not stored in plaintext in the database - they are hashed, and in addition they are UTF-16le encoded.

If the only thing you need is to verify if user is who they claim to be, simply **bind as that user** to authenticate them:

```
// ... preparation code
if (ldap_bind($ldap, $userSuppliedName, $userSuppliedPassword)) {
    // credentials are valid
} else {
    // credentials are invalid
}
```

This approach takes care of **all authentication rules** available in Active Directory - that includes, but is not limited to, logon hours, workstation restrictions, password expirations, invalid logon attempts etc. Simply comparing the passwords does not tell you anything about the above.

Comment: Thanks. I encounter same error for all fields not only password. Also, I only have a single username and password (admin/123456 in the exmple code.) that works with bind function. The customer asked me to use this credential to verify other users. And I do not know how do that.

Comment: Well, using a dedicated account to verify other users' credentials is usually recommended for openLDAP and similar systems, but definitely not required for AD. You are saying you only have a single username and password: but then where are your users' credentials that you want to verify?

Comment: Other usernames and passwords does not work using ldap_bind functions. (invalid credential  warning). Should I do something on AD server? I am a open source developer and I do not know a lot about MS solutions.